# Cocos2d-x c++ How to capture touch event on OpenGL lines draws

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have some openGL drawing , it is lines and im using DrawPrimitives::drawLine
in fact im using many drawLine's,
is there any way to capture touch on the lines. and also the lines are moving (following other node).
her is the draw line code:

```
void EditPart::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    Sprite::draw(renderer, transform, flags);

    _customCmd.init(_globalZOrder);
    _customCmd.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(EditPart::onDraw, this, transform, flags);
    renderer->addCommand(&_customCmd);
}
void EditPart::onDraw(const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    Director* director = Director::getInstance();
    CCASSERT(nullptr != director, "Director is null when seting matrix stack");
    director->pushMatrix(MATRIX_STACK_TYPE::MATRIX_STACK_MODELVIEW);
    director->loadMatrix(MATRIX_STACK_TYPE::MATRIX_STACK_MODELVIEW, transform);

    if (bDrawControlPolygon)
        {
            glLineWidth( 2.0f );             
            DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4B(255,255,0,255);
            DrawPrimitives::drawLine(Vec2(Point0->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point0->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2),Vec2(Point1->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point1->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2));

            DrawPrimitives::drawLine(Vec2(Point1->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point1->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2),Vec2(Point2->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point2->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2));

            DrawPrimitives::drawLine(Vec2(Point2->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point2->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2),Vec2(Point3->getPositionX() + MovablePointSIZE2,Point3->getPositionY() + MovablePointSIZE2));

        } 

    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();

    director->popMatrix(MATRIX_STACK_TYPE::MATRIX_STACK_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: You can know where a touch is made, and you know where your lines are, as you are drawing them. So what about adding a touch handler and check if the position is close enough to your lines?

Comment: yeah i was thinking about it to keep all lines in vector but i can end up with allot of coordinates